# component not re rendering when call action in mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm using mobx v6.
HomePage calls `roomStore.fetchRooms` when scrolls down to bottom, yes I use IntersectionObserver and lodash/throttle function for implement infinite scroll.

I checked `roomStore.fetchRooms` been called when `loadMore` function called, and `roomStore.homeRoomList` been updated.
All functions change states in Mobx stores are decorated with @action.
I wonder why my HomePage component is not re-rendered.

```
//RoomStore
export default class RoomStore extends BasicStore {
  @observable homeRoomList: GetRoomsPayload["rooms"] | null;

  constructor({root, state}: { root: RootStore, state: RoomStore}){
    super({root, state});
    makeObservable(this);
    this.homeRoomList = state?.homeRoomList ?? null;
  }

  async fetchRooms(category?: string, page:number = 0){
    const [error,response] = await this.api.GET<GetRoomsPayload>(`/room/${category}?page=${page}`);
    if(error){
      throw Error(error.error)
    }
    if(response && response.success){
      const { data } = response
      this.feedFetchHomeRooms(data.rooms);
      
      return response.data;
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  @action.bound
  feedFetchHomeRooms(rooms: GetRoomsPayload["rooms"]){
    if(rooms){
      if( this.homeRoomList) {
        this.homeRoomList = [...this.homeRoomList, ...rooms];
      }
      else {
        this.homeRoomList = rooms;
      }
    }  
  }
}

// HomePage Component
const HomePage: FC & HomePageInitStoreOnServer = ({}) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const homeRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);
  const infiniteScrollTargetRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const { roomStore } = useMobxStores();
  
  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    throttleFetch();
  }

  const throttleFetch = useCallback(throttle(() => {
    roomStore.fetchRooms()
  },500),[]);

  useInfiniteScroll({
    target: infiniteScrollTargetRef,
    cb: handleLoadMore,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!roomStore.homeRoomList){
     roomStore.fetchRooms() 
    }
  },[]);
  
  return (
      <section >
        <RoomContainer ref={homeRef}>
          {roomStore.homeRoomList?.map((room: any) => {
                return (
                  <Card
                    room={room}
                    key={room.id}
                  />
                );
              })}
        </RoomContainer>
        <InfiniteScroll targetRef={infiniteScrollTargetRef}/>
      </section>
  );
};


export default observer(HomePage);
```

Answer (score 0):

The component (HomePage) that renders observable data needs to be wrapped into the observer.

```js
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'

const HomePage = observer(() => {
  // your code of component 
})
```

you can find more details [in official docs here](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#always-read-observables-inside-observer-components)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's already been wrapped when export as default